# about recaptcha validation

Tags: php, recaptcha

Im working with a php form validation, which involves reCAPTCHA as well. 
Once the form is submitted, I validate the form fields, and store the error messages like

```
if( !$this-> valid_username($username) ){
            $this->error = "username is invalid <br />";    
    }
```

and similarly other fields.
    Now, How can I access the `$response->is_valid` in my validation class so that I can display the captcha error sth like

```
if( !$response->is_valid ){
            $this->error .= "Invalid captcha. <br />";  
    }
```

The idea is to display all fields errors at once.
    I hope my question is clear, I'd appriciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exacly sure what you mean but I guess you need this:
http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html

first include the usual reCAPTCHA library like this:

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "your_private_key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                              $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                              $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                              $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
```

Then you can check the result like you mentioned above:

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    $this->error .= "Invalid captcha. <br />";
  }
```